# Centering a popup FLUID div

Tags: css

Good day

centering elements are easy, when they have defined widths and heights: eg.

width: 500px;
height: 400px;

Problem comes with Fluid Layouts:

But I have a modal popup(lightbox) that I use to enlarge thumbnail images...:

**Problem** is that I cannot get it to center, it floats left-top...I want it to be **absolutely centered: vertical and horizontal**

Here is my modal popup code
Also see my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yKezB/2/) to see what i mean(try resizing the viewport)

HTML:

```
<div id="imageModal">
    <div id="close_button">X</div>
    <div id="imageHolder"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#articleFeatured img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 113px;
}
#imageModal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1024;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(50, 50, 50);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#imageModal #imageHolder {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #0088cc;
}
#imageModal #imageHolder img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
#close_button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity:0.8;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 45px;
    max-height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: your test page doesn't show anything. by the way it's very easy to center things with CSS without knowing their width/height...there are endless discussing about it here.

Comment: Click on the image to see something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you define fluid dimensions to your width and height, you need to add fluid dimensions to your positioning properties: top, left etc

Let say you have:

```
#parent {

    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    /*(or relative)*/
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;

    text-align: center;
}
```

the top size + the left size = remaining size from either width or height. So 25%(top) + 25%(left) = 100% - 50%(width)...

So using another width, height will yield:

```
#parent {

    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    /*(or relative)*/
    top: 40%;
    left: 40%;

    text-align: center;
}
```

SEE the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5HCWu/26/)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you center unknown width/height: http://jsfiddle.net/nhGLH/2/

### HTML

```
<div class='centered'>
    you can change the width and height 
    of this and it will always be centered
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.centered{ 
    // mus have width & height 
    width:400x;  
    height:250px; 
    // absolute position must have all directions set to "0"
    position:absolute;
    left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;
    // final centering trick
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but you gave it a FIXED width and height. i am looking for centering a fluid div: one with percentile widths and heights

Comment: I did it only for the sake of example, it does not have to be that way, it can change...

Answer (score 0):

Give Following CSS,

```
#imageModal #imageHolder img {
        margin 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I see that giving the img itself a margin: 0 auto will center it horizontally, but not vertically...How would you suggest that?

Comment: visit : http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/

Answer (score 0):

I had to change a couple of places in order to make it work properly. Change markup slightly and added some CSS to support vertical alignment.

```
<div id="articleFeatured">
    <div class="img">
        <div class="close_button">X</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/115/food/1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Check working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yKezB/12/

Comment: thank you, but your image is aligned top left...see the accepted answer - It was what I was looking for...Apologies if I did not articulate my question well

Comment: @DextrousDave Click this image to see the demo in action :)